# How to use ls to find files for a specific set of dates in Unix

Tags: bash, unix, command

I have a set of files in a directory. I need to find files for a set of specific dates (For example if i need files from 16th Jan to 20th Jan). I tried using `ls -ltr | grep <date>` but it is taking too many steps to accomplish selecting the files. Is there any easier way to get this done. Thanks!

Comment: Shash, have a think about the accepted answer, I think find may be a better tool for the job.

Comment: @paxdiablo Ok., will try even that

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'm not sure how many files you have in *your* directory but something like this should be blindingly fast:

```
ls -al | awk '$6 == "Jan" && $7 >= 16 && $7 <= 20 {print $9}'
```

On my system, I see the following with dates slightly modified:

```
pax> ls -al | awk '$6 == "Jan" && $7 >= 16 && $7 <= 29 {print $9}'
kids_shares.ods
our_savings.gnumeric
photos

pax> ls -ald kids_shares.ods our_savings.gnumeric photos
-rw-r--r--   1 pax pax 51005 Jan 29 19:39 kids_shares.ods
-rw-r--r--   1 pax pax  2275 Jan 28 14:48 our_savings.gnumeric
drwxrwxrwx 130 pax pax  4096 Jan 29 21:47 photos
```

You can see that the dates match for the given files.

One thing to watch out for: if the file is recent, it will have a time in column 8. Beyond some age, `ls` starts putting the year in there. I have the vague recollection that it's somewhere around the six-month-old border but I'm not absolutely certain. You'll need to cater for that as well.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) instead, that will be much easier.

```
find . -mtime -$start -mtime +$end
```

Comment: `find` has a `-newer` flag (to see if it's newer than another file) but unfortunately not an `-older` one. I'm not sure it's suited to these very specific date ranges.

Comment: @paxdiablo it is suitable, I just added an example (also, find has `!` (not) operator)

Comment: Ooh, I didn't think of that. Good call.

Answer (score 8):

You're better off using `find`. Start by creating two temp files with specific times to search between. `touch` can do this:

```
touch -t "201301160001" ./start
touch -t "201301202359" ./finish
```

Then run `find`:

```
find /path/to/files -type f -newer ./start ! -newer ./finish
```

Comment: Actually, both these find-based solutions are probably better than mine - just may need to use maxdepth if you don't want to go into  subdirectories. +1 for both.

Comment: @paxdiablo: Thanks mate. I reciprocated because (although I prefer not to parse `ls` output) the OP _did_ want it done that way, and `awk` was a good choice.

Comment: This works great for me interactively but returns no results when used in a script (either with `./script.sh`, `bash script.sh` or `source script.sh`). I think it's to do with the bang; when I use `bash -x`to debug, it's being surrounded with single quotes; running the command this way returns nothing.